# Adding bootstrap.js to browserify?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, browserify

So I am trying to figure out how to do this? I downloaded bootstrap-sass via bower and added the bootstrap javascript into a shim.

A few things have me confused, the bootstrap.js file looks like this.

```
//= require bootstrap/affix
//= require bootstrap/alert
//= require bootstrap/button
//= require bootstrap/carousel
//= require bootstrap/collapse
//= require bootstrap/dropdown
//= require bootstrap/tab
//= require bootstrap/transition
//= require bootstrap/scrollspy
//= require bootstrap/modal
//= require bootstrap/tooltip
//= require bootstrap/popover
```

This is kind of self explanatory, but still confusing at the same time, do I leave it commented like that? When I add to the bootstrap shim do I include just the bootstrap.js file, or should I link to all the ones I need?

Just to save myself from hacking away (which I will be doing in the meantime), I'd like to try to get some information on how to include bootstrap.js into browserify.

**Edit:** I think I might just have to concat all the files I need and include that script, because when I browserify the bootstrap.js I just get the above.

I'll try without the comments, then if that fails I'll concat all the scripts into one file and see what happens :)

**Edit:** Hmm looks like the concat theory works! The only thing is jQuery, take a look.

```
; jQuery = global.jQuery = require("c:\\wamp\\www\\mysite\\app\\client\\requires\\jquery\\js\\jquery.js");
/* ========================================================================
 * Bootstrap: affix.js v3.1.1
 * http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix
 * ========================================================================
 * Copyright 2011-2014 Twitter, Inc.
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)
 * ======================================================================== */
```

This is my compiled browserify code, the only way to get it to work when I call a bootstrap function say for example `$('body').modal('toggle')` I have to change the `jQuery` above to `$` manually.

I tried using both inside my shim but still same thing I must manually write `$`. Example

```
// Notice I use $ here not jQuery like above, this is the only way to get it to work!
; $ = global.jQuery = require("c:\\wamp\\www\\mysite\\app\\client\\requires\\jquery\\js\\jquery.js");
/* ========================================================================
 * Bootstrap: affix.js v3.1.1
 * http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix
 * ========================================================================
 * Copyright 2011-2014 Twitter, Inc.
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)
 * ======================================================================== */
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This answer is by the original questioner. It was posted as an edit to the question. I moved it here, where the answers go.

> I recompiled and it looks like it's working now, make sure inside your
>   shim you use `$`
>
> ```
> "bootstrap": {
>     "exports": "bootstrap",
>     "depends": {
>         "jquery": "$"
>     }
> },
> ```

Comment: Yeah I figured that out, browserify can be really frustrating but when in doubt I realized just fiddle with the shim.

Comment: Just for answering and giving the correct solution ill mark this, even though I had it...

Comment: Thanks, that was generous of you.

Comment: Can you add some more context to your answer? I have the same problem, but don't get your answer. Tried to add your json to my bower.json, but that didn't help.

Comment: this has to be added to package.json, not bower.json.. and it works but you have to write this : "browserify-shim": {
        "bootstrap": {
            "exports": "bootstrap",
            "depends": [
                "jquery:$"
            ]
        }
    }

Comment: @Unispaw I am pretty sure I am missing something here, but it's not working for me (error: Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery ). Here is a repo to replicate the error I am seeing https://github.com/Chandu/browserify-test

Comment: I changed the "jquery:$" to  "jquery:jQuery" and it works now.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to use [Webpack](http://webpack.github.io/), which has a script-loader to load jQuery at the global context.

Comment: I'm using it like this `require("jquery");
require('jquery-ui');
require('bootstrap-sass');`
Still message is the same.